# How to split numbers for projects spanning over multiple months in multiple years in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Here is the data for my problem

| Project Name | Total Savings | Realization Start Date | Realization End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project A | $10000 | 1/3/2023 | 4/20/2023 |
| Project B | $20000 | 2/10/2023 | 3/25/2023 |
| Project C | $15000 | 3/1/2023 | 6/15/2023 |

The output is required in table visual as

| Months | Total Savings |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | X |
| Feb | Y |
| Mar | Z |

Months from DimCalendar and Savings values
Also, year-to-date savings measure is required in the report.

I am unable to split the savings over days in the calendar and use it by aggregating functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to spread the amounts evenly over the dates

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Date", each List.Transform({Number.From([Realization Start Date])..Number.From([Realization End Date])}, each Date.From(_))),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Savings", each [Total Savings]/List.Count([Date])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Total Savings", "Realization Start Date", "Realization End Date"}),
#"Expanded Date" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Date")
in #"Expanded Date"
```

[image]

Comment: I have a doubt, by the end of the year the number of projects will cross 1K count. Will this report refresh given the number of rows are being generated? Any ideas how to handle it?